# If I address which professor I want to work with in SOP for PhD application, what are the actual odds that I end up working with them? (pure math, US)

Tags: phd, mathematics

I am preparing for math PhD application next year, and I've seen many advice that it would be a good idea to address who I want to work with and what area of math I want to specialize in. But I was wondering if it's actually worth the time investigating each professor in different universities and consider my potential advisor over overall prestige of each school, when I vaguely know each area of math. Pure math PhD students have to pass qualifying exams and finish 2 years of masters program, and those are not short periods and one might change his areas of interest, so I'm unsure it's actually worth choosing advisor over prestige. Or, one may argue that top 30 programs usually take students who already know what they are going to do. Any advice?

Comment: Why a single person? I suggest that instead of trying to chose/predict an advisor at this point (U.S. perspective), you should focus more generally on whether there is a group of people working on things you think you'd be interested in. For example, if you're interested in set-theoretic topology (I picked this because many universities do not have a group of two or more people in this area), then you'll want to look at universities that have a few people working in set-theoretic topology and evidence of seminars for these people and their graduate students.

Comment: Do you have fields of math which you like?

Comment: Yes but it's very limited and I'm still trying to learn new areas